# Alamofire: Define order of parameters

Tags: swift, alamofire

I define two parameter that I need to attach to my url to get some data with Alamofire in Swift 3:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["id": String(mID), "getfunction": "w"]

    Alamofire.request("https://myurl.tld", parameters: parameters).response { response in
        print("Request: \(response.request)")
        print("Response: \(response.response)")
        print("Error: \(response.data)")
```

In my understanding the URL should be resolved to this:

> https://myurl.tld/?id=xxxxxxxx&getfunction=w

but Alamaofire changes the URL to this:

> https://myurl.tld/?getfunction=w&id=xxxxxxxx

which does not work for me. So I think Alamofire uses the parameters in alphabetical order. Is there a way to use the parameters in the order I have defined them?
The problem is that I need to use a few more parameters in my final call and then the parameters have to be in the correct order.

Comment: `the parameters have to be in the correct order` Here's your issue, it's not Alamofire's fault. A dictionary order is undefined by design.

Comment: if your parameters order does matter, then you can combine your parameters into your request `url` directly, without using the `parameter`. But you need to encode the url yourself.

Comment: did you found a way to do this? having the same issues